# Relationship many to many between objects not working for me in Android Room

Tags: android, android-room

I have a many to many relationship between the tables `lh_salmodia` and `lh_salmo`.

`lh_salmodia`

```
salmodiaId   liturgiaId    salmoFK    orden
    1         300010201       7         1
    2         300010201       8         2
    3         300010201       9         3
    4         300010301       5         4
   ...
```

`lh_salmo`

```
salmoId    salmo     pericopaId     salmoRef
   7       Text A         1           RefA
   8       Text B         2           RefB
   9       Text C         3           RefC
   5       Text D         4           RefD
  ...
```

Both tables are related by `salmoFK` and `salmoId` columns and the purpose is to obtain a set of psalms grouped by the `liturgiaId` column (which in turn is related to another table, it is a more complex model and I do not dwell on that detail).

Following the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships) I have defined the following entities:

For `lh_salmodia`:

```
@Entity(tableName = "lh_salmodia",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(
                entity = Salmo.class,
                parentColumns = "salmoFK",
                childColumns = "salmoId",
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
        indices={
                @Index(value={"liturgiaId","salmoFK"},unique = true)}
)
public class Salmodia {
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "salmodiaId")
    public Integer salmodiaId;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "liturgiaId")
    public Integer liturgiaId;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "salmoFK")
    public Integer salmoFK;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "orden")
    public Integer orden;

    public void setSalmodiaId(Integer salmodiaId) {
        this.salmodiaId = salmodiaId;
    }
    public Integer getSalmodiaId() {
        return salmodiaId;
    }

    public void setLiturgiaId(Integer liturgiaId) {
        this.liturgiaId = liturgiaId;
    }
    public Integer getLiturgiaId() {
        return liturgiaId;
    }

    public Integer getSalmoFK() {
        return salmoFK;
    }
    public void setSalmoFK(Integer salmoFK) {
        this.salmoFK = salmoFK;
    }

    public Integer getOrden() {
        return orden;
    }

    public void setOrden(Integer orden) {
        this.orden = orden;
    }

}
```

For `lh_salmo`:

```
@Entity(tableName = "lh_salmo")
public class Salmo {
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "salmoId")
    public Integer salmoId;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "salmo")
    public String salmo;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pericopaId")
    public Integer pericopaId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "salmoRef")
    public String salmoRef;

    public void setSalmo(String salmo) {
        this.salmo = salmo;
    }
    public String getSalmo() {
        return salmo;
    }

    public void setSalmoRef(String salmoRef) {
        this.salmoRef = salmoRef;
    }

    public String getSalmoRef() {
        return salmoRef;
    }

    public Integer getSalmoId() {
        return salmoId;
    }
    public void setSalmoId(Integer salmoId) {
        this.salmoId = salmoId;
    }

    public Integer getPericopaId() {
        return pericopaId;
    }

    public void setPericopaId(Integer pericopaId) {
        this.pericopaId = pericopaId;
    }
}
```

To express the relationship between the above entities I have created this class:

```
public class SalmodiaWithSalmos {
    @Embedded
    public Salmodia salmodia;
    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "salmoFK",
            entityColumn = "salmoId",
            entity = Salmo.class,
            associateBy = @Junction(SalmodiaSalmoCrossRef.class)
    )
    public Salmo salmoId;

}
```

And to express the cross reference:

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = {"salmoId", "salmoFK"})

public class SalmodiaSalmoCrossRef {
    @NonNull

    public Integer salmoFK;
    @NonNull
    public Integer salmoId;

}
```

Finally in the DAO:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM lh_salmodia WHERE liturgiaId=:liturgiaId")
public LiveData<List<SalmodiaWithSalmos>> getSalmos(Integer liturgiaId);
```

According to what is said in the documentation, doing this I should get a list of `Salmo` objects, but when testing the code I am getting `null` in the `salmoId` property. I get a list of `Salmodia` objects without problem, but from the `Salmo` table I get no data. What is wrong with my code? Is there something I have not understood correctly in the documentation?

In summary, I want to obtain the values of the table `lh_salmo`, joining said table with `lh_salmodia` (because I need to verify the value of `liturgiaId` in the WHERE of the SQL query).

Answer (score 1):

> What is wrong with my code? Is there something I have not understood correctly in the documentation?

I guess (not going to read through the documentation) that you may be expecting Foreign Keys to provide values. Rather:-

For a many to many relationship you would typically utilise a third table that has two columns (both as a composite primary key). One column references/maps/relates/associates to one table, the other column likewise to the other table.

- Rather than trying to embed a self-reference, which would limit to a many to one.

Here's a working example based upon your code (but with some changes).

First **Salmodia** (PS I would recommend using Long/long rather than Integer int for id columns)

```
@Entity(tableName = "lh_salmodia"
        /*,
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(
                entity = Salmo.class,
                parentColumns = "salmoFK",
                childColumns = "salmoId",
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
        indices={
                @Index(value={"liturgiaId","salmoFK"},unique = true)}

         */
)
public class Salmodia {
   @NonNull
   @PrimaryKey
   @ColumnInfo(name = "salmodiaId")
   public Integer salmodiaId;

   @NonNull
   @ColumnInfo(name = "liturgiaId")
   public Integer liturgiaId;

   /*
   @NonNull
   @ColumnInfo(name = "salmoFK")
   public Integer salmoFK;
    */

   @NonNull
   @ColumnInfo(name = "orden")
   public Integer orden;

   public Salmodia(){}

   @Ignore
   public Salmodia(int salmodiaId, int liturgiaId, int orden) {
      this.salmodiaId = salmodiaId;
      this.liturgiaId = liturgiaId;
      this.orden = orden;
   }

   public void setSalmodiaId(Integer salmodiaId) {
      this.salmodiaId = salmodiaId;
   }
   public Integer getSalmodiaId() {
      return salmodiaId;
   }

   public void setLiturgiaId(Integer liturgiaId) {
      this.liturgiaId = liturgiaId;
   }
   public Integer getLiturgiaId() {
      return liturgiaId;
   }

   /*
   public Integer getSalmoFK() {
      return salmoFK;
   }
   public void setSalmoFK(Integer salmoFK) {
      this.salmoFK = salmoFK;
   }

    */

   public Integer getOrden() {
      return orden;
   }

   public void setOrden(Integer orden) {
      this.orden = orden;
   }

}
```

- Foreign key dropped
- SalmoRef dropped
- Constructors added to simplify usage (@Ignore hides constructor from Room)

**Salmo** (construstors added) :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "lh_salmo")
public class Salmo {
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "salmoId")
    public Integer salmoId;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "salmo")
    public String salmo;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pericopaId")
    public Integer pericopaId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "salmoRef")
    public String salmoRef;

    public void setSalmo(String salmo) {
        this.salmo = salmo;
    }
    public String getSalmo() {
        return salmo;
    }

    public Salmo(){}

    @Ignore
    public Salmo(int salmoId, String salmo, int pericopaId, String salmoRef) {
        this.salmoId = salmoId;
        this.salmo = salmo;
        this.pericopaId = pericopaId;
        this.salmoRef = salmoRef;
    }

    public void setSalmoRef(String salmoRef) {
        this.salmoRef = salmoRef;
    }

    public String getSalmoRef() {
        return salmoRef;
    }

    public Integer getSalmoId() {
        return salmoId;
    }
    public void setSalmoId(Integer salmoId) {
        this.salmoId = salmoId;
    }

    public Integer getPericopaId() {
        return pericopaId;
    }

    public void setPericopaId(Integer pericopaId) {
        this.pericopaId = pericopaId;
    }
}
```

NEW MAPPING TABLE **SalmodiaSalmoMap**

```
@Entity(
        primaryKeys = {"salmodiaIdMap","salmoIdMap"},
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = Salmodia.class,
                        parentColumns = "salmodiaId",
                        childColumns = "salmodiaIdMap",
                        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                ),
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = Salmo.class,
                        parentColumns = "salmoId",
                        childColumns = "salmoIdMap",
                        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                )
        }
)
class SalmodiaSalmoMap {
    @NonNull
    public Integer salmodiaIdMap;
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    public Integer salmoIdMap;

    public SalmodiaSalmoMap(){}
    @Ignore
    public SalmodiaSalmoMap(int salmodiaIdMap, int salmoIdMap) {
        this.salmodiaIdMap = salmodiaIdMap;
        this.salmoIdMap = salmoIdMap;
    }
}
```

**SalmoWithSalmodias** rather than the reverse also uses the mapping table

```
class SalmoWithSalmodias {
    @Embedded
    Salmo salmo;
    @Relation(
            entity = Salmodia.class,
            parentColumn = "salmoId",
            entityColumn = "salmodiaId",
            associateBy = @Junction(
                    value = SalmodiaSalmoMap.class,
                    parentColumn = "salmoIdMap",
                    entityColumn = "salmodiaIdMap"
            )
    )
    List<Salmodia> salmodiaList;
}
```

- Obviously you could have a SalmodiaWithSalmos

An abstract class annotated with @Dao for accessing **AllDAO**

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract long insert(Salmodia salmodia);
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract long insert(Salmo salmo);
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    abstract long  insert(SalmodiaSalmoMap salmodiaSalmoMap);
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM lh_salmo")
    abstract List<SalmoWithSalmodias> getAllSalmosWithTheirSalmodias();
}
```

An @Database annotated class **TheDatabase**

```
@Database(
    entities = {
            Salmodia.class,
            Salmo.class,
            SalmodiaSalmoMap.class
    },
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDAO getAllDAO();

    private static volatile TheDatabase instance = null;
    static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase.class,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

- note runs on main thread for convenience/brevity

To demonstrate usage **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TheDatabase db;
    AllDAO dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getAllDAO();

        dao.insert(new Salmo(7,"TEXTA",1,"REFA"));
        dao.insert(new Salmo(8,"TEXTB",2,"REFB"));
        dao.insert(new Salmo(9,"TEXTC",3,"REFC"));
        dao.insert(new Salmo(5,"TEXTD",4,"REFD"));


        dao.insert(new Salmodia(1,300010201,1));
        dao.insert(new Salmodia(2,300010201,2));
        dao.insert(new Salmodia(3,300010201,3));
        dao.insert(new Salmodia(4,300010201,4));

        dao.insert(new SalmodiaSalmoMap(1,7));
        dao.insert(new SalmodiaSalmoMap(2,8));
        dao.insert(new SalmodiaSalmoMap(3,9));
        dao.insert(new SalmodiaSalmoMap(4,5));

        // extras
        dao.insert(new SalmodiaSalmoMap(1,8));
        dao.insert(new SalmodiaSalmoMap(1,9));
        dao.insert(new SalmodiaSalmoMap(1,5));

        for(SalmoWithSalmodias sws: dao.getAllSalmosWithTheirSalmodias()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Salmo is " + sws.salmo.salmo + " ID is " + sws.salmo.salmoId + " it has " + sws.salmodiaList.size() + " Salmodias, they are :-");
            for (Salmodia sia: sws.salmodiaList) {
                Log.d("DBINFO","\tSalmodia ID is " + sia.salmodiaId + " LiturgiaId is " + sia.liturgiaId + " Orden is " + sia.orden);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Finally the **Results**

The log :-

```
2022-03-25 10:21:40.911 D/DBINFO: Salmo is TEXTD ID is 5 it has 2 Salmodias, they are :-
2022-03-25 10:21:40.911 D/DBINFO:   Salmodia ID is 4 LiturgiaId is 300010201 Orden is 4
2022-03-25 10:21:40.911 D/DBINFO:   Salmodia ID is 1 LiturgiaId is 300010201 Orden is 1
2022-03-25 10:21:40.912 D/DBINFO: Salmo is TEXTA ID is 7 it has 1 Salmodias, they are :-
2022-03-25 10:21:40.912 D/DBINFO:   Salmodia ID is 1 LiturgiaId is 300010201 Orden is 1
2022-03-25 10:21:40.912 D/DBINFO: Salmo is TEXTB ID is 8 it has 2 Salmodias, they are :-
2022-03-25 10:21:40.912 D/DBINFO:   Salmodia ID is 2 LiturgiaId is 300010201 Orden is 2
2022-03-25 10:21:40.912 D/DBINFO:   Salmodia ID is 1 LiturgiaId is 300010201 Orden is 1
2022-03-25 10:21:40.912 D/DBINFO: Salmo is TEXTC ID is 9 it has 2 Salmodias, they are :-
2022-03-25 10:21:40.912 D/DBINFO:   Salmodia ID is 3 LiturgiaId is 300010201 Orden is 3
2022-03-25 10:21:40.912 D/DBINFO:   Salmodia ID is 1 LiturgiaId is 300010201 Orden is 1
```

The tables via App Inspection:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. But why would you need a `SalmodiaSalmoMap` table? My idea is to express the relationship using `lh_salmodia` whose reason for being is precisely to express the relationship between an `liturgiaId` and the corresponding psalms. Isn't a new relation via `SalmodiaSalmoMap` redundant?

Comment: @A.Cedano SalmodiaSalmoMap is equivalent to your SalomodiaSalmoCrossRef (I didn't see that when I did the above as I was trying to follow all the references and foreign keys).

Comment: Because of your answer, I realized that I was missing a table in the relation. The three tables are: **`liturgia`** (`liturgiaId`) -> **`lh_salmodia`** (`liturgiaId`, `salmoId`) <- **`lh_salmo`** (`salmoId`). For this case I was needing a [nested object relationship](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#nested-relationships), so my problem was solved by defining a new entity similar to `UserWithPlaylistsAndSongs` (documentation), in which I have put the `Liturgia` entity and the `SalmodiaWithSalmos` entity. Doing this, I can get the data in `lh_salmo`.